# Logic operation: Select two values from a column in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, slice, numpy-slicing

I have a data frame as follows,

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'one', 'six'],
                    'b' : ['x', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'x'],
                    'c' : np.random.randn(7)})
```

I want to select data from df2 where column 'a' equals 'two' or 'three', my code is as follows,

```
df2[df2['a']=='two'or df2['a']=='three']
```

Could anyone give me some light on why my code doesn't work?

Error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

is that `isin`

```
slice=df2.loc[df2.a.isin(['one','two'])].copy()
slice
Out[797]: 
     a  b         c
0  one  x -0.064378
1  one  y  0.344902
2  two  y -0.080087
4  two  y  1.433515
5  one  x  1.065794
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `|` instead of `or`

```
df2[(df2['a']=='two') | (df2['a']=='three')]
```

Comment: I know '|' is bitwise and or is a logic, but I am confused why here I need to use | rather than or, could you explain a little bit? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're close but you need to do a few things, first use the `|` operator to specify an or statement, secondly put each condition in brackets,

This should work

`df2.loc[(df2['a']=='two') | (df2['a']=='three')]`